# Angular-cli 8 - Is it possible to build only on es2015?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

In version 8 of angular-cli, the build is done 2x. One in es5 and one in es2015.

Is it possible to build only on es2015?

Changing the target to es5, it is done only in es5 .. But I have not found a way to do it only in es2015.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you update your [browserslist](https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist) accordingly (`.browserlistrc`-file or `browserlist`-Array in `package.json`) and only add browsers which are capable of ES2015, only one build should be created.

For example, when using

```
"browserslist": [
  "> 5%"
]
```

I only get one build instead of two builds for `es5` and `es2015`. (Okay, to be fair, only chrome makes it into the list with `> 5%`...)

(You can also check with `npx browserslist` for a list of browsers that would currently be supported with your project setup. Also, see the ["Differential Loading"-part here](https://blog.ninja-squad.com/2019/05/29/angular-cli-8.0/) for a detailed explanation.)

Comment: I have been trying to do the same but the solution does not produce index.html with script type=module but having the default browserlistrc does with both es5 and es2015 builds with script types nomodule and module.

Answer (score 10):

You need to add the line `defaults` and put the word `not` at the begin of every line below in  the file `browserlist`.  For example:

```
defaults
not > 0.5%
not last 2 versions
not Firefox ESR
not dead
not IE 9-11 # For IE 9-11 support, remove 'not'.
```

After that you can check changes by the command `npx browserslist`. It should print nothing.