# Ionic 4 + Electron not works

Tags: ionic-framework, electron, ionic4

I am having problems to start a new Electron + Ionic project.

I have followed this tutorial:

https://www.9lessons.info/2018/10/ionic-electron-desktop-app.html

But when I run the project with the command:

```
npm run electron-serve
```

I get this errors on dev-tools console and the screen is white:

```
  runtime-es2015.33b5e618b3baf74c7138.js:1 Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

main-es2015.64da9645e917002baf25.js:1 Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

polyfills-es2015.1b94da7ab13e05353bf7.js:1 Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

/Users/myuser/ionic/Frontend/myproject/src/myproject/node_modules/electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Resources/electron.asar/renderer/security-warnings.js:145 Electron Security Warning (Insecure Content-Security-Policy) This renderer process has either no Content Security
    Policy set or a policy with "unsafe-eval" enabled. This exposes users of
    this app to unnecessary security risks.

For more information and help, consult
https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/security.
 This warning will not show up
once the app is packaged.
(anonymous) @ /Users/myuser/ionic/Frontend/myproject/src/myproject/node_modules/electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Resources/electron.asar/renderer/security-warnings.js:145
```

What would be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For someone with the same problem:

Is not really a Capacitor bug, but a build problem in your part related to the Angular 8 build settings not being compatible with electron.

Changing the target in tsconfig.json from es2015 to es5, or add

```
"browserslist": [
  "> 5%"
]
```

in the package.json

[Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56400290/white-screen-on-fresh-new-angular-8-electron-5-app)

Solves the problem

Answer (score 1):

Easy, Just go to src/tsconfig.json -> change the line "target" : "es2015" into "target" : "es5" then re-run "npm run electron-serve" on the terminal and the app should work.

This works for Windows 10, Ionic 5.2.7, Electron 6.0.10